# Function works correctly, except through another module, no visible reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, modularity

There is an issue I don't understand. I have two customized modules in a directory.
Note the following codes were voluntarily shorten. I give the function that does not work, and another one which is similar but works.
Let's see:

`module_parsing.py`

```
import re

def hippodrome_numreu_prix(response):
        """Parse the hippodrome's name, number of the meeting and prize's name.
        response -- html page. Arrival table.
        returns a tuple as (hippdrome's name, nb of meeting, prize's name)
        """
        #hippodrome means racecourse, but this word exists in English
        #There are several races on a hippodrome for a particular day, that's called a meeting("reunion" in French). On a particular day there are several meetings too. So that's why we call it number of meeting: n°1, n°2...
        #A race is for a prize ("prix" in French). This prize has a name.
        hip_num = response.xpath("//html//h1[@class='CourseHeader-title']/text()").extract() 
        hip_num = ''.join(hip_num)
        #HIPPODROME
        if re.search('-\s{0,5}([A-zÀ-ÿ|-|\s]+)\s{0,5}/', hip_num):
            hippo = re.search('-\s{0,5}([A-zÀ-ÿ|-|\s]+)\s{0,5}/', hip_num).group(1).lower().replace(' ','')
        else:
            hippo = None
        #NUMBER OF MEETING
        if re.search('R[0-9]+', hip_num):
            num_reunion = re.search('R[0-9]+', hip_num).group()
        else:
            num_reunion = 'PMH'
        #PRIZE
        prix = response.xpath("//html//h1[@class='CourseHeader-title']/strong/text()").extract_first().lower()
        return (hippo,num_reunion,prix)

def allocation_devise(response):
    """Parse the amount of allowance and currency (€, £, $, etc)
    response -- html page. Arrival table.
    returns a tuple as (allowance's amount, currency's symbol)
    """
    #"allocation" means allowance. That's sum of the prizes for winners: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.
    #"devise" means currency. Depending of the country of the hippodrome, the allowance are expressed in different currencies.
    alloc_devise = response.xpath("//html//div[@class='row-fluid row-no-margin text-left']/p[2]/text()[2]").extract_first()
    #ALLOWANCE
    if re.search(r'[0-9]+',alloc_devise.replace('.','')):
        alloc = int(re.search(r'[0-9]+',alloc_devise.replace('.','')).group())
    else:
        alloc = None
    #CURRENCY
    if re.search(r'([A-Z|a-z|£|$|€]+)',alloc_devise):
        devise = re.search(r'([A-Z|a-z|£|$|€]+)',alloc_devise).group()
    else:
        devise = None
    return (alloc, devise)
```

`module_correction.py` has a dependency with the previous one:

```
from module_parsing import *

def fonction_parse_correction(
        champ_corrige, response):

    dico_fonction_parse = {
    'allocation': allocation_devise,
    'devise': allocation_devise,
    'hippodrome':hippodrome_numreu_prix,
    'reunion' : hippodrome_numreu_prix,
    'prix': hippodrome_numreu_prix,
    }
    if champ_corrige in {'allocation','hippodrome'}:
        return dico_fonction_parse[champ_corrige](response)[0]
    elif champ_corrige in {'devise','reunion'}:
        return dico_fonction_parse[champ_corrige](response)[1]
    elif champ_corrige in {'prix'}:
        return dico_fonction_parse[champ_corrige](response)[2]
```

Now when I am in scrapy shell to test my function:

```
scrapy shell https://www.paris-turf.com/programme-courses/2019-07-09/reunion-chateaubriant/resultats-rapports/prix-synergie-1150124
#Here I change the path with sys.path.insert() and only import module_correction
In [1]: from module_correction import *
In [2]: fonction_parse_correction('hippodrome',response)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-e82fe121aab0> in <module>
----> 1 fonction_parse_correction('hippodrome',response)

~/.../scrapy_project/scrapy_project/module_correction.py in fonction_parse_correction(champ_corrige, response)
    103         if champ_corrige in {'allocation','hippodrome'}:
--> 104             return dico_fonction_parse[champ_corrige](response)[0]
    105         elif champ_corrige in {'devise','reunion'}:

~/.../scrapy_project/scrapy_project/module_parsing.py in hippodrome_numreu_prix(response)
    157     #HIPPODROME 
--> 158     if re.search('-\s{0,5}([A-zÀ-ÿ|-|\s]+)\s{0,5}/', hip_num):
    160         hippo = re.search('-\s{0,5}([A-zÀ-ÿ|-|\s]+)\s{0,5}/', hip_num).group(1).lower().replace(' ','')
    161     else:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

It turns weird when I execute `allocation_devise()` through `fonction_parse_correction()`, because it works:

```
In [3]: fonction_parse_correction('allocation',response)      
Out[3]: 35000
```

and this more weird when I simply copy and paste `hippodrome_numreu_prix()` function in the shell to execute it by itself as:

```
In [4]: hippodrome_numreu_prix(response)
Out[4]: ('châteaubriant', 'R1', 'prix synergie')
```

So here, I clearly see there is no problem of `None` type because `search()` clearly finds it. Besides, it seems this is not a problem of use it by a `dict` because the similar function `allocation_devise()` works well, and even works on the same argument `response`.
What is wrong that I don't see ?

Notes: Ubuntu 18.04, Scrapy 1.5.2, Python 3.7.1

Comment: As a minor remark - don't use non-enligsh identifiers in a code. For example i don't understand a thing from your code, even tho i'm fluent in python.

Comment: @Radoslaw Cybulski that's not that I won't use english identifiers, that's more if I start to change the name of instances I may forget to change the other corresponding ones and that's not understandable for anybody after it. But don't hesitate to tell which one are clearly problematic for you.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the value of `hip_num` that triggers this behaviour.  More practically, I would evaluate  `re.search('-\s{0,5}([A-zÀ-ÿ|-|\s]+)\s{0,5}/', hip_num)` _once_ and assign the result to a variable rather than evaluating it twice.